# Compile c++ application to standalone executable running without having to install it

Tags: c++, compilation, exe

I have a small C++ application that only creates some files, and I want to export it as an .exe file. I tried to copy the *PROJECT\Debug\PROJECT.exe* but when I run it on an other computer it says "This file needs VCRUNTIME140D.dll to run which was not found on your system".

I just need a way of creating an exe that works on any Windows system when you simply click run it.

Comment: Then you should statically link the runtime.

Comment: 2 problems (1): `VCRUNTIME140D.dll` is the debug C-runtime support dll - even if you wanted to you are not allow to distribute this; (2) change the compiler switches to use the statically linked C-runtime support. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx

Comment: Do not use dynamic linking. Instead link statically. Google static linking. That should help.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question.  The answer is that the OP needs to use /MT or /MTd to create his program.  He will *probably* find that compiling in release mode is enough to make it work (because somebody else will have installed VCTRUNTIME140.dll).